# Hide text of text area based on a condition in angular

Tags: angular

I have a textarea and I want to hide the text of the textarea based on a condition

```
`<textarea class="form-control" 
  [ngClass]="{'pointer-events-none cursor-disabled' :  
  model.userPrivilage.canNewButNotEdit() }" 
  [(ngModel)]="model.repSetUp.DESCR" name="DESCR">
</textarea>`
```

Comment: if the value will be empty  & text area will be disabled then what is the point of showing it to the user? Simply hide that control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things either disable text area or hide text area on condition, I am giving both use as you want :

```html
<-- Disable textarea -->
<textarea class="form-control" 
  [disabled]="model.userPrivilage.canNewButNotEdit()"
  [(ngModel)]="model.repSetUp.DESCR" name="DESCR">
</textarea>

<-- hide textarea -->
<textarea class="form-control" 
  [ngClass]="{'hide 
  model.userPrivilage.canNewButNotEdit() }" 
  [(ngModel)]="model.repSetUp.DESCR" name="DESCR">
</textarea>

<-- hide text on codition -->
<textarea class="form-control" 
  [value]="(model.userPrivilage.canNewButNotEdit() ? '' : model.repSetUp.DESCR)"
  [(ngModel)]="model.repSetUp.DESCR" name="DESCR">
</textarea>
```